# Chage the color of a series of an asp:Chart

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-applications

I created an asp:Chart. In this chart are two bars for every month showing the effort estimation and actual charging of every month for all projects.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiCa7.png)

It should be a bit like this chart. left should show the actual charging and right the effort estimation.
Now I like to have the actual charging and the budget of a project in the same color. I tried to program it like this.

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dtblProjectAnalysisProductive.Rows)
    {
       EmployeeChart.Series.Add(row["OrderName"].ToString() + " EstimatedEffort");
       EmployeeChart.Series[row["OrderName"].ToString() + " EstimatedEffort"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
       EmployeeChart.Series[row["OrderName"].ToString() + " EstimatedEffort"]["StackedGroupName"] = "EffortEstimation";
       EmployeeChart.Series[row["OrderName"].ToString() + " EstimatedEffort"].Color = EmployeeChart.Series[row["OrderName"].ToString()].Color;
    }
```

But this don't work. If I debug the code, no property of the series set a color.
So can some one help me with this problem or tell me, at which time the color of the series is set?

Comment: what will happen if you do this EmployeeChart.Series[row["OrderName"].ToString() + " EstimatedEffort"].Color = Color.Red ?

Comment: Then the bar gets red, but I like to have it in the color of the same project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you OnPostPaint event in asp:chart

```
<asp:CHART id="Chart1" ..  OnPostPaint="Chart1_PostPaint">
```

c#

```
 protected void Chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
 {
   Chart1.Series["Series2"].Color = Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color;
 }
```

I am not sure the best way to do this. Please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.7.2) and find the best.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much!